# Does the OP have the right to deny a bounty on their question offered by another user?

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation, bounty, users

Any user who has >75 reputation can offer a bounty on a question, even if the question is not theirs. The question is, **should the question OP have the right to deny/disapprove of a bounty offered by another user?**

For example, the OP might not want someone else to offer a bounty on a question of theirs because it's not well-received by the community, and the OP doesn't want the question to receive more attention because it could get downvoted.

Comment: There are other ways to prevent this from happening: deleting the question, voting to close your question, disassociating it from your account, or improving the question enough that any new attention would be neutral/positive. FWIW, I can't see someone putting a bounty on a negative score question if it's still in bad shape (at least not without editing it themselves).

Comment: @BSMP:  If the question was poor but the answer was exemplary, I could see one putting a bounty on the question to award that specific answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are some *peculiar* circumstances...but ultimately, the OP doesn't have the ability to refuse others from putting a bounty on a question, regardless of the reason.

Note:

- If the question is subject to downvoting, then the altruist was doing the community a favor by exposing it to a wider audience, and allowing that sort of moderation to happen.
- If the OP doesn't feel like someone doesn't deserve a bounty on an answer, then their opinion is expressed through voting.  **They don't sacrifice any reputation if someone else offers the bounty.**